# AngularJS ng-show doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show

I have the following code:

```
<header class="hero-unit" id="banner" ng-include="'components/header/header.html'"></header>

<div ng-include="'components/navbar/navbar.html'"></div>


<div class="container">
    <h3 class="site-headline">Opret nyt produkt</h3> <hr>
    <form> 
        <div class="container jumbotron">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <select ng-model="selectedOption">
                    <option ng-repeat="option in options">
                        {{ option.name }}
                    </option>
                </select>

            </div>

            <div ng-show="selectedOption.name == Pool" ng-include="'components/new/new-pool.html'">test</div>

        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<footer class="footer" ng-include="'components/footer/footer.html'"></footer>
```

And I'm trying to show the ng-include whenever `selectedOption == "Pool"`, but the ng-include is being shown even though the ng-show condition isn't true.

I've tried with `" ==='Pool'"` and without the `'` , but nothing seems to work, and I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Use `ng-if="selectedOption.name == Pool"`

Comment: Doesn't work with the `ng-if`

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing `selectedOption.name == Pool`, which happens to be `undefined == undefined`. Because of how you set up your `ng-select` you just want to compare:

`selectedOption === 'Pool'`

See [this simple plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/FBGlVfw5x2KDiWZlUOMf?p=preview).

Comment: I have no idea why this isn't working, but it's not. I hides the `ng-show` but doesn't show it whenever I choose Pool

Answer (score 1):

Either make your model for the `select` to be `selectedOption.name` or your conditional to be `ng-show="selectedOption == 'Pool'"` Your conditional is looking for a different variable than you've set for the `select` (`selectedOption` vs. `selectedOption.name`).  (also note the quotes around 'Pool')

And I'm not sure but you might need to give your `option` elements a value.

Comment: Changing the `selectedOption`to just be that, and then `ng-show="selectedOption == 'Pool'"` didn't work, neither did the other way around

Comment: @Tony's plunk below does it exactly this way, and it works.  Maybe something else going on?

Answer (score 0):

**I managed to find my problem**

Somehow, I managed to create a space so it didn't say

```
Pool
```

But it said

```
 Pool
```

Changing from this:

```
<option ng-repeat="option in options">
    {{ option.name }}
</option>
```

To this:

```
<option ng-repeat="option in options">{{ option.name }}</option>
```

Solved my problem.

Comment: Oddly enough, just like my plunk. =) But, this is a good time to point out, you shouldn't use `<option ng-repeat...>` to create a select. You can read the [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) for more.

Comment: Or you could put option.name as the value for the option `<option value="{{ option.name }}'>{{ option.name }}</option>`.  Useful if you wanted to apply some special formatting to the display text without affecting the logic value.

Comment: @Tony Thank you. I will look into that :) Didn't realize that Angular had a directive for the select tag